# Why it's the else statement executed and if it's ignored?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm having a problem with a Python script, the if branch it's not executed, no matter what parameters I give to the script. Is it something wrong with my code? I'm executing an HTML form and the result was OK until I've added some content to the else statement..I've tried everything but it still doesn't want to work...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pymysql
import cgi
from http import cookies
# Open database connection
db = pymysql.connect("localhost","superadmin","123","dinamic" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()
data=cgi.FieldStorage()
a=data.getvalue('e1')
b=data.getvalue('p1')

# Prepare SQL query to fetch a record into the database.
sql = "SELECT id, email, password FROM register WHERE email = %s AND password = %s"
try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute(sql, (a, b))
   # Commit your changes in the database
   db.commit()
   c=cookies.SimpleCookie()
   # assign a value
   c['mou']=a

   # set the xpires time
   c['mou']['expires']=24*60*60

   # print the header, starting with the cookie
   print (c)
   print("Content-type: text/html", end="\r\n\r\n", flush=True);
   print('''<html><head><title>First python script for Security and Encrpytion class</title></head><body><center><h2>Successfully login!</h2><br><img src='image/2.gif'></body></html>''');

except:
   db.commit()
   print("Content-type: text/html", end="\r\n\r\n", flush=True);
   print("<html>");
   print("<body>");
   print("<center>")
   print("<h2>Fail to login!</h2>");
   print("<img src='image/dinamic.gif'>");
   print("</body>");
   print("</html>");
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()
```

Comment: you're swallowing up the error, find out what the `try/except` is hiding

Comment: @Sayse what do you mean? As I've said, I've added a few lines to the else statement and now everything it's not working

Comment: adding lines isn't going to help, remove the `try/except` to find out what error is occuring that you're not handling correctly

Comment: Make sure the query works when you execute it manually. `cursor.execute` returns number of affected rows, so to run `else` that returned number would be 0

Comment: I Don't think cursor.execute returns the number of rows selected, it returns the number of rows affected by DDL statements.

Comment: @Barmar exactly

Answer (score 1):

`cursor.execute()` doesn't return the number of rows that were selected. You can call `cursor.fetchone()` to see if it returns a row.

There's also no need to call `db.commit()` since you haven't made any changes.

```
try:
    # Execute the SQL command
    cursor.execute(sql, (a, b)))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row:
        c=cookies.SimpleCookie()

        # assign a value
        c['mou']=a

        # set the xpires time
        c['mou']['expires']=24*60*60

        # print the header, starting with the cookie
        print (c);
        print ("Content-type: text/html", end="\r\n\r\n", flush=True);
        print("");
        print('''<html><head><title>Security & Encryption class - First script</title></head><body><h2>successfully login!</h2>''');
        print("<center>");
        print("<img src='image/successfully.gif'>");
        print("</center>");
        print("</body></html>");
    else:
        print ("Content-type: text/html", end="\r\n\r\n", flush=True)
        print("<html>")
        print("<body>")
        print("<center>")
        print("<h2>Login fail!</h2>")
        print("<img src='image/dinamic.gif'>")
        print("<br><br>")
        print('<button id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button" >Home</button>')
        print('''<script type="text/javascript">
         document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
             location.href = "index.html";
         };
        </script>''');
        print("</center>");
        print("</body>");
        print("</html>");
except:
    # Rollback in case there is any error
    db.rollback()
```

Comment: Then you must be giving an incorrect email or password. If you're hashing the password, you can't use `and password = %s` in the query.

Comment: if I'm eliminating the data from the else statement and I only put the <h2> I can successfully login, so I think it's a problem with the query

Comment: Try removing the `try/except`. Maybe you're getting an error and you're not seeing it.

Comment: Then it must be that the username and password don't match. I don't see anything wrong with the query.

Comment: they match with the database, if I m using the PHP it s working without a problem, but Python simply refuses to do this...I ve updated my code to see where it s my problem

Comment: Try using `print(repr(a), repr(b))` to make sure the variables contain what you expect. There's nothing wrong with the query as far as I can tell.

Comment: Now you're never fetching anything from the query, so you can't tell if it returned anything.

Comment: So basically I should add cursor.fetchone()?

Comment: I added a `print` statement for debugging purposes. See my edit.

Comment: Of course. That's the whole point of my answer.

Comment: now I get ,,malformed header from script 'login.py': Bad header: None"

Comment: That's because `print(row)` is before the header. Use Developer Tools to see the raw response.

Comment: in the get section of the 500 error I can see my 2 variables, but if I'm entering directly into the console I can only see the 500 error, not the variable

Comment: If you're seeing the two variables, then it has to go into the `if`, not `else`. I can't explain why it's not working for you. Now take out the `print` and try again.

Comment: if I'm taking out the print it will still execute only the else, and not the if :(

Comment: I can't explain it, sorry. Good luck, but I don't think I can help you any more.